# Make Sleepwatcher daemon run on display wake - OSX 10.8.3?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, macports

I have installed Sleepwatcher using Macports on my 10.8.3 computer, following this guide pulled from this post (https://discussions.apple.com/message/17966344#17966344):

> MacPorts is one of the most effective and simplest ways to install Terminal based add-ons. First, of course, install MacPorts, which is as easy as downloading a package and running it.
>
> 1. To install Sleepwatcher via MacPorts, simply type in the command line:
>
>    sudo port install sleepwatcher
>
> then type:
>
> ```
> sudo port load sleepwatcher
> ```
>
> Sleepwatcher will then automatically be installed and loaded.
>
> 1. You need to actually convert your AppleScripts into a Shell Script (they are not the same). The way to do this is to load it into the
>      .sleep or .wakeup script that you desire to be placed in your Home
>      folder. The way to do this is to do the following:   To Create a
>      Script to be Run When Your Computer Goes to Sleep/Wakes Up:
>
> a.) type in a new Terminal Window:
>
> ```
> cat > $HOME/.wakeup then
>
> #!/bin/sh
> ```
>
> b.) The next thing to understand is that you can run Applescripts through Terminal, via something called osascript, which
>   is a command given within the Terminal. If your Applescript is fairly
>   simple (just ejecting a disk or opening a new Finder window), I would
>   go ahead and write that in osascript language. To gain a better idea
>   of what that means, go to this website. However, it looks like you've
>   saved your Applescript as a file. This next solution might be a little
>   bit simpler. The following will help you just run your Applescript
>   from the file you've saved it as (assuming it is a .scpt or
>   something).   After typing the above commands, type: osascript
>   followed by a space. Then drag your Applescript file to the Terminal
>   window. Thus, your command should look something like: osascript
>   /path/to/desired/script
>
> c.) Hit enter.
>
> d.) Hit ^D (Ctrl-D)
>
> e.) Then type chmod +x $HOME/.wakeup

This worked great for me.

But, what I want is to run a simple Applescript on display wake. However, right now, the daemon only runs on wake from sleep, not wake from display sleep. How do I make it run on wake from display sleep? I can do it in the terminal, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it using the launchdaemon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this stuff myself, but looking at the man file it seems you can update your .plist file ~/Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist to use the flag "-W" for "displaywakeupcommand" instead of "-w" for "wakeupcommand" (unless you can use both?).

Comment: I had to add that flag to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist` and run `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility-localuser.plist`